# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to connect to a database with python using sqlite3 module and i gets an error - ***sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error***

---

> I searched some solutions for this but i did not got the solution. I
>   am new to sqlite3

---

```
def insert_into_db(url, title, description, keywords):
    con = sqlite3.connect('index.db')
    c = con.cursor()
    create = r'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS index (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,url VARCHAR,description TEXT,keywords TEXT);INSERT INTO index(url, title, description, keywords)VALUES('{}','{}',{}','{}');'''.format(url, title,description, keywords)
    c.execute(create)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

---

help me to  get rid of this error **:(**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INDEX` is a keyword in SQLite3. Thus, it'll be parsed as a keyword. There are several ways around this, though.

According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), you could use backticks or quote marks to specify it as a table name. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `index` ...
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "index" ...
```

may work.

You can pass arguments to your sql statement from the `execute()` command. Thus,

```
create = r'''CREATE TABLE ... VALUES(?,?,?,?);'''  # use ? for placeholders
c.execute(create, (url, title, description, keywords))  # pass args as tuple
```

This is more secure compared to formatting your arguments directly with Python.

Note also that SQLite's syntax for autoinc is `AUTOINCREMENT` without the underscore and they require the field to also be an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: when i add backticks and run it ,i get this error-**sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error**

Comment: @SakithKarunasena Try without the underscore.

Comment: no **AUTOINCREMENT** also do not work and i get the same error

Comment: @SakithKarunasena You'll need `PRIMARY KEY` right after `INTEGER`. (You can also drop the `NOT NULL` since the pkey makes it redundant.

Comment: All rowid table INTEGER PRIMARY KEY columns auto increment, btw. The AUTOINCREMENT keyword isn't needed unless you specifically want the changes it causes in the normal behavior: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 2):

You can not name a table `index`. `INDEX` is a reserved keyword.

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) states:

> The SQL standard specifies a large number of keywords which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object.

Comment: when i change the table name to search_index and run it i get this error-**sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error**